# Resolve this problem about area of circle

Tags: circles, problem-solving, area

I spent a few days thinking about how to solve this problem without using the formula of the circle, anyone have any ideas?

Here you can find a picture with the [problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xdXoG.jpg)

Thank you!

Comment: Please write the question here, and upload any necessary images.

Comment: What is "the formula of the circle"?

Comment: you can write the area as the integrale of a function,from? to ?

Comment: Is the problem from a calculus course?

Comment: You drew 3 circles in the figure, with the ratio of their radii $1:2:3$. The ratio of the area is then $1:4:9$.

Comment: I posted the image, because I think it is better. It should be very easy. If you need the question I can rewrite it, but you will need the picture in order to see the figure. I understand that the formula of the circle means the area (pi*r²).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The ratios of the areas of the semi-circles with radius $AB, BD, AD$ is $1:4:9$. Let $S_{AB}$ denote the area of the semicircle with diameter $AB$. Then, we can see that the shaded area can be derived by $$S_{shaded} = \frac{S_{AD}-S_{BD}+S_{AB}}{S_{AD}}\cdot S_{AD} = \frac{9-4+1}{9}\cdot \frac{1}{2}\cdot S_{circle} = 27\pi$$
where we used the fact that $S_{AD} = \frac{1}{2}S_{circle}$.

Comment: That's why I was looking for, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Maybe the task wants you to use ratios?

If you put $S=81\pi$ the area of circle with diameter AD, then for the areas of circles with diameters BD and AB we have:

$$ S_{BD} = \bigl( \frac{2}{3}\bigr)^2S$$ 
$$ S_{AB} = \bigl( \frac{1}{3}\bigr)^2S$$

Since $BD=\frac{2}{3}AD$ and $AB=\frac{1}{3}AD$ .

Then you can compute area of the shaded region this way:
$$ S_{shaded}=\frac{1}{2}S_{AB}+(\frac{1}{2}S-\frac{1}{2}S_{BD})$$

Comment: That's the solution I was looking for, using ratios!

Answer (score 0):

Hint :
Compute first the area of the shadded region in the upper semi circle. You know that the total area of the upper semi-circle is $\frac{81}{2} \pi$. And you can compute how much you need to remove ($\frac{36}{2} \pi$) to get the exact answer .

Then compute the shadded region in the lower semi circle. ($9 \pi$)

Answer (score 0):

We will divide the whole figure into 6 regions as shown below:-

[image]

Let n(A) = [2] + [3] + [3’] and n(B) = [2’] + [3’] + [3].

Note that [1] = [1’]; [2] = [2’] and [3 = [3’]. By symmetry, n(A) = n(B).

$ n(A \cup B) = [Whole] – [Green]$

$n(A \cap B) = [3’] + [3] = [Red]$

By inclusion-exclusion, we have $2 \times n(A) = n(A) + n(B) = n(A \cup B) + n(A \cap B)$

The required $= \dfrac 12 ([Whole] – [Green] – [Red])$